# Unable to fetch more than 10k records

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, parse-platform

I am developing an app where I have more than 10k records added to a class in parse. Now I am trying to fetch those records using PFQuery( I am using the "***skip***" property). But I am unable to fetch records beyond 10k and I get the following error message

***"Skips larger than 10000 are not allowed***"

This is a big problem for me since I need all the data.

Has anybody come across such problem. Please share your views.

Thanks

Comment: are you bringing 10k register to memory?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is indeed due to the cost of mongo skip operations. You can formulate a query such that you don't need the skip operator. My preferred method is to orderBy objectId and then add a condition that objectId > last yielded objectId. This type of query can be indexed and remain fast, unlike skip pagination, which has a O(N^2) cost in seeks.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption would be that it's based on performance issues with MongoDB's [skip](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/) implementation.

> The cursor.skip() method is often expensive because it requires the server to walk from the beginning of the collection or index to get the offset or skip position before beginning to return result. As offset (e.g. pageNumber above) increases, cursor.skip() will become slower and more CPU intensive. With larger collections, cursor.skip() may become IO bound.